# C++/CLI WinForms: BeginInvoke Error

Tags: .net, multithreading, winforms, c++-cli, begininvoke

I am unable to figure out the reason for this error:

> Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.

**Here is my (stripped) code:**

```
private: delegate void MyDelegate(Object^ openFileDialog1);
ListView^ myDelegate;

private: void import_links(Object^ openFileDialog1) {
            myDelegate = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ListView());
            myDelegate->BeginInvoke( gcnew MyDelegate( this, &Form1::import_links ), openFileDialog1);

            //do some work here
}
private: System::Void Import_LinkClicked(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs^  e) {
        OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;

        if ( openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK )
        {
            Thread^ importThread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ParameterizedThreadStart(this,&Form1::import_links));
            importThread->Start(openFileDialog1);
        }
    }
```

Please let me know the solution.

Comment: If I add this condition: if(myDelegate->InvokeRequired), then I get cross-thread operation not allowed error.

Comment: Call `myDelegate->CreateControl()` to force the creation of the handle, or just add the control to a parent control, making sure it's visible. BTW, why did you name it `myDelegate`? It's a `ListView`, certainly not a delegate.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I am trying to perform a cross-thread operation i.e. updating main thread element in another thread I just created in above code. I know there is something wrong with my code. After calling CreateControl() I'm now facing this error: Cross-thread operation not valid. Could you please let me know what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        myDelegate = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ListView());
```

Basic problems with this statement:

- It is not a delegate, it is a ListView object
- Controls have a strong association with the thread on which they are created.  Creating a control on a worker thread like you do is never correct
- A control requires a Parent to become visible and useful, it doesn't have one
- A control requires the thread to run a dispatcher loop so it can get messages.  Such a thread must call Application::Run().  Your worker thread doesn't
- The underlying window for a control is created lazily, when needed to become visible.  Since it doesn't have a parent and isn't visible, there wasn't any need to create the window yet.  So it won't have a valid Handle property, as the exception tells you
- BeginInvoke() ensures that the invoked code runs on the thread that owns the control.  Since it is the worker thread that owns it, BeginInvoke() can never actually invoke to another thread

You already have a reference to an object that is owned by the correct thread.  It is `this`.  So correct code would look like:

```
void import_links(Object^ openFileDialog1) {
    if (this->InvokeRequired) {
       this->BeginInvoke( gcnew MyDelegate( this, &Form1::import_links ), openFileDialog1);
    }
    else {
        //do some work here
    }
}
```

But do note the ultimate fallacy, you created a worker thread and the *only* thing it does is call `this->BeginInvoke()`.  That takes a fraction of a microsecond.  Creating a thread to do so little work is never useful.

Refactor your code, use a BackgroundWorker.  Let its DoWork event handler *only* do the kind of things that are expensive, like importing a file.  Let its RunWorkerCompleted event *only* do the kind of things that need to happen on the UI thread, such as displaying the result of the import and hiding the "I'm working on it" notification.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough. Your answer helped me to learn a lot. It's been only 3 days learning C++/CLI and my concept of delegates was not clear. With the help of your answer, I was able to correct my code and it's working fine now with thread. I creating this app. for the purpose of learning so I had to learn how to work with threads. I already know how to use BackgroundWorker.